# External Table GPFDIST Filehost on Community Edition

Tags: greenplum

I am attempting to load data from a *.csv file off my VM of the Greenplum Community edition; however, I am having issues creating the external table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL 
    TABLE flightinfo (flightid int, airline_id int, carrier character(2), fl_num int)
    LOCATION ('gpfdist://home/gpadmin/Desktop/flighttable.csv') FORMAT 'CSV';
```

This keeps giving an error where it is unable to translate the host name...I've tried with localhost and others, but still nothing appears to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

External table declarations need the name of the host, the port your gpfdist instance is listening on, and the filename.

If you have gpfdist running on port 8000 in directory /localhome/gpadmin/Desktop:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL 
TABLE flightinfo (flightid int, airline_id int, carrier character(2), fl_num int)
LOCATION ('gpfdist://localhost:8000/flighttable.csv') FORMAT 'CSV';
```

Comment: I found out what was going on. I had declared the gpfdist service to point to the /home/gpadmin/desktop path and had a redundancy in the CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE script, essentially having gpfdist look for the file in /home/gpadmin/desktop/home/gpadmin/desktop.

It is simple and yet I Failed to look at that for hours. I need more sleep. Thanks KaBar.